# powershell extract string from variable to assign another variable

Tags: regex, powershell

I'd like to run an external process and capture its command output in a variable in PowerShell. I'm currently using this:
I will capture `"D:\reports\20191122_174015_hostname"` then to assign to another variable.

```
$OutputVariable = (command) | Out-String
```

$OutputVariable :

```
Gathering system informations
  Discovered server
  failed to 1 of 5 server, for details see: C:\TEST
failed.log
  Output for HOSTNAME at: C:\OUTPUT_11222019
Gather DONE
Execution time: 32 secs
To create a report for server, run one of the following:
  capacity   : test.exe --report --capacity "D:\reports\20191122_174015_hostname"
  traditional: test.exe --report --traditional "D:\reports\20191122_174015_hostname"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are attempting to extract a varying path from a string, you will need to have some way of identifying only that specific path. In this case, you can use `-match` for creating regex matching criteria.

```
$null = $OutputVariable -match 'capacity.*?"([^"]+)"'
$Matches[1]
```

Alternatively, the `Match` method from the .NET Regex class could be used as well.

```
[regex]::Match($outputvariable,'capacity.*?"([^"]+)"').Groups[1].Value
```

**Explanation:**

- `capacity` matches capacity literally
- `.*?` matches as few characters as possible. This basically gets us to the first `"` character after capacity.
- `"` matches `"` literally
- `([^"]+)`: `[^"]` matches anything not a `"` and matches one or more times (`+`). The `()` create a capture group that we can reference later. The capture group is named `1`.

A successful match will result in two entries stored in the automatic variable `$Matches`. Index 0 is the entire matching string, and index 1 is the first capture group. Since you only want to see the path, we only retrieve data from index 1. `$Matches` ***will not update if there is no match. So it can retain previous matching values.***

`$null` is used to suppress the output of the `-match` operator.

**Note:** This assumes the path is surrounded by double quotes preceded at some point by the word capacity. In reality, you may want to tweak this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```bsh
$OutputVariable = Get-Process
$OutputVariable | Out-File -FilePath "D:\Program Files\tool\var\global\reports\20191122_174015_hostname"
```